# Why don't we use xor (or nand)?

Tags: soft-question, convention

Why don't we use xor more often in ordinary mathematics?

For example, every integer is even xor odd; for every real number $x\ne y$, we have $x<y$ xor $x>y$; a graph is bipartite xor it contains an odd cycle; given an ultrafilter in a boolean algebra, every element xor its complement in the boolean algebra is in the ultrafilter; etc.

My main question is about the notation xor used to label the connective, but a related question would be on why the logical connective xor itself doesn't appear more often in our proofs and theorems. My broader question therefore would be about why we are inclined to use some logical connectives more often in mathematics and others not so much (eg. nand). Is there a meta-mathematical reason for this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133074/discussion-on-question-by-okoyos-why-dont-we-use-xor-or-nand).

Answer (score 2):

The xor of two statements is the equivalence of one of them to the negation of the other. More generally, the xor of $n$ statements is defined as the assertion that the number of them that are true is odd. This is especially inconvenient in stating either the antecedents or consequents of theorems, which are naturally stated as material conditionals and hence as inclusive disjunctions. And we frequently wish to state some $n$ statements are all equivalent. Further, the inclusive disjunction of $n$ statements - i.e. the claim that at least one of them is true - is also frequently useful, e.g. because some claim of interest follows from any one of them.

Answer (score 0):

One reason is that it is easier to prove a non-exclusive disjunction: simply prove one disjunct or the other.

Another reason is that it is easier to define the exclusive disjunction in terms of the non-exclusive disjunction than the other way around: the exclusive disjunction is the non-exclusive disjunction plus the claim that the disjuncts are mutually exclusive. If you are writing a proof, you can simply say something like "either $A$ or $B$, but not both" to express the exclusive disjunction. There is no reason to introduce the neologism "xor" into the language when a simple "but not both" will do.

Comment: Yes, it could be argued that xor does not appear as often as iff and wouldn't be that much more convenient in using than just saying "but not both". Actually, Terence Tao makes a similar argument in his introductory analysis book based on frequency against using xor although this doesn't answer the deeper question of why it doesn't appear as often.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the same reason why we use implications rather than equivalence (in this case: if x is not odd, then x is even) - we do not care about cases if both of the statements are true. In proofs, we split it into two cases (x is odd / x is even) and never use the fact that the other statement might (not) be true as well.

I feel like this is the convenience of two state logic; the only case where we would be "lying" is if we found x that is not even or odd (like extending our domain to rational numbers).

Comment: But we *do* use equivalences in proofs. The reason why we use implications is that more often than not we only have those; this is inherent to the fact that we *want* to be working in a deductive system, i.e. a set-up where all the problems we face are special cases of our premises.